# iOS - Twitter like contact selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, contacts, uikeyboard

How would I manage to build a UI like this part of the Twitter for iOS app? When I select the @ sign it dissapears the inputAccessoryView and shows a table view in its places, any idea how I can do something similar?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain all they do is set the inputAccessoryView to nil, resize the UITextView, then display a UITableView with the search results.

To reverse, they set the inputAccessoryView to that tool bar, resize the UITextView, and remove the UITableView from its superview.